# Why is this recursion so much faster than equivalent iteration?

Tags: c++, recursion

I've been told many times that recursion is slow due to function calls, but in this code, it seems much faster than the iterative solution. At best, I typically expect a compiler to optimize recursion into iteration (which looking at the assembly, did seem to happen).

```
#include <iostream>

bool isDivisable(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = y; i != 1; --i)
        if (x % i != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
bool isDivisableRec(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 1)
        return true;
    return x % y == 0 && isDivisableRec(x, y-1);
}

int findSmallest()
{
    int x = 20;
    for (; !isDivisable(x,20); ++x);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << findSmallest() << std::endl;
}
```

Assembly here: https://gist.github.com/PatrickAupperle/2b56e16e9e5a6a9b251e

I'd love to know what is going on here. I'm sure it is some tricky compiler optimization that I can be amazed to learn about.

Edit: I just realized I forgot to mention that if I use the recursive version, it runs in about .25 seconds, the iterative, about .6.

Edit 2: I am compiling with -O3 using

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

Though, I'm not really sure what that matters.

Edit 3:
Better benchmarking:
Source: http://gist.github.com/PatrickAupperle/ee8241ac51417437d012
Output: http://gist.github.com/PatrickAupperle/5870136a5552b83fd0f1
Running with 100 iterations shows very similar results

Edit 4:
At Roman's suggestion, I added -fno-inline-functions -fno-inline-small-functions to the compilation flags. The effect is extremely bizarre to me. The code runs about 15x faster, but the ratio between the recursive version and the iterative version remains similar. 
https://gist.github.com/PatrickAupperle/3a87eb53a9f11c1f0bec

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84282/discussion-on-question-by-patrick-why-is-this-recursion-so-much-faster-than-equi).

Comment: Do you care about understanding the unexpected behavior here, or are you trying to perform calculations of this particular type fast?  This is a least-common-multiple problem, and it may be a lot faster to factor the numbers `2...n` and take the supremum over cardinality of each unique prime factor, rather than doing trial divisions.

Comment: You should remove output statements within the timed code. Output is extremely slow thing. So is dynamic allocation.

Comment: I think, function inlining is the cause. Try compilation with `-fno-inline-functions -fno-inline-small-functions` flags.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am curious about this particular code. The speed is meaningless to me, but the difference is intriguing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I thought about that, but 25 lines of output in 25 seconds should do almost nothing. Also, both sets have the same exact output.

Comment: @Roman Adding those flags had an extremely surprising effect: https://gist.github.com/PatrickAupperle/3a87eb53a9f11c1f0bec
Still a big difference, though. And still favoring recursion. Way faster, though.

Comment: Upvoted, because right now this is an interesting question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [this](https://gist.github.com/PatrickAupperle/ee8241ac51417437d012) code I also see large timing difference (in favor of the recursive version) with GCC 4.9.3 in Cygwin. I get

```
13.411 seconds for iterative
4.29101 seconds for recursive
```

Looking at the assembly code it generated with `-O3`, I see two things

- The compiler replaced tail recursion in `isDivisableRec` with a cycle and then *unrolled the cycle*: each iteration of the cycle in the machine code covers *two* levels of the original recursion.

  ```
  _Z14isDivisableRecii:
  .LFB1467:
      .seh_endprologue
      movl    %edx, %r8d
  .L15:
      cmpl    $1, %r8d
      je  .L18
      movl    %ecx, %eax          ; First unrolled divisibility check
      cltd
      idivl   %r8d
      testl   %edx, %edx
      je  .L20
  .L19:
      xorl    %eax, %eax
      ret
      .p2align 4,,10
  .L20:
      leal    -1(%r8), %r9d
      cmpl    $1, %r9d
      jne .L21
      .p2align 4,,10
  .L18:
      movl    $1, %eax
      ret
      .p2align 4,,10
  .L21:
      movl    %ecx, %eax          ; Second unrolled divisibility check
      cltd
      idivl   %r9d
      testl   %edx, %edx
      jne .L19
      subl    $2, %r8d
      jmp .L15
      .seh_endproc
  ```
- The compiler *inlined* several iterations of `isDivisableRec` by lifting them into `findSmallestRec`. Since the value of `y` parameter of `isDivisableRec` is hardcoded as `20` the compiler managed to replace the iterations for `20`, `19`...`15` with some "magical" code inlined directly into `findSmallestRec`. The actual call to `isDivisableRec` happens only for `y` parameter value of `14` (if it happens at all).

  Here's the inlined code in `findSmallestRec`

  ```
      movl    $20, %ebx
      movl    $1717986919, %esi      ; Magic constants
      movl    $1808407283, %edi      ; for divisibility tests
      movl    $954437177, %ebp       ;
      movl    $2021161081, %r12d     ;
      movl    $-2004318071, %r13d    ;
      jmp .L28
      .p2align 4,,10
  .L29:                              ; The main cycle
      addl    $1, %ebx
  .L28:
      movl    %ebx, %eax             ; Divisibility by 20 test
      movl    %ebx, %ecx
      imull   %esi
      sarl    $31, %ecx
      sarl    $3, %edx
      subl    %ecx, %edx
      leal    (%rdx,%rdx,4), %eax
      sall    $2, %eax
      cmpl    %eax, %ebx
      jne .L29
      movl    %ebx, %eax             ; Divisibility by 19 test
      imull   %edi
      sarl    $3, %edx
      subl    %ecx, %edx
      leal    (%rdx,%rdx,8), %eax
      leal    (%rdx,%rax,2), %eax
      cmpl    %eax, %ebx
      jne .L29
      movl    %ebx, %eax             ; Divisibility by 18 test
      imull   %ebp
      sarl    $2, %edx
      subl    %ecx, %edx
      leal    (%rdx,%rdx,8), %eax
      addl    %eax, %eax
      cmpl    %eax, %ebx
      jne .L29
      movl    %ebx, %eax             ; Divisibility by 17 test
      imull   %r12d
      sarl    $3, %edx
      subl    %ecx, %edx
      movl    %edx, %eax
      sall    $4, %eax
      addl    %eax, %edx
      cmpl    %edx, %ebx
      jne .L29
      testb   $15, %bl               ; Divisibility by 16 test
      jne .L29
      movl    %ebx, %eax             ; Divisibility by 15 test
      imull   %r13d
      leal    (%rdx,%rbx), %eax
      sarl    $3, %eax
      subl    %ecx, %eax
      movl    %eax, %edx
      sall    $4, %edx
      subl    %eax, %edx
      cmpl    %edx, %ebx
      jne .L29
      movl    $14, %edx
      movl    %ebx, %ecx
      call    _Z14isDivisableRecii   ; call isDivisableRecii(x, 14)
      ...
  ```

The above blocks of machine instructions before each `jne .L29` jump are divisibility tests for `20`, `19`...`15` lifted directly into `findSmallestRec`.  Apparently, they are more efficient than the tests used inside `isDivisableRec` for a run-time value of `y`. As you can see, the divisibility by 16 test is implemented simply as `testb   $15, %bl`. Because of this, non-divisibility of `x` by high values of `y` is caught early by the above highly optimized code.

None of this happens for `isDivisable` and `findSmallest` - they are basically translated literally. Even the cycle is not unrolled.

I believe it is the second optimization that makes for the most of the difference. The compiler used highly optimized methods of checking divisibility for higher `y` values, which happen to be known at compile time.

If you replace the second argument of `isDivisableRec` with an "unpredictable" run-time value of `20` (instead of hard-coded compile-time constant `20`), it should disable this optimization and bring the timings in line. I just tried this and ended up with

```
12.9 seconds for iterative
13.26 seconds for recursive
```

Comment: Wow. That's really cool. 
Thank you for this answer, it is exactly what I was looking for. I'm surprised gcc optimized the recursive version so much better, but at least I now know what it did.